# Blocking read from input file continuous streaming

Tags: go, julia

I have a file open that I am constantly writing to in Golang and reading in julia live.  For some reason my code fails that it read EOF at the first blocking read.  What am I doing wrong?

```
  ERROR: LoadError: EOFError: read end of file

  R.buffer = open("data/live.bin", "r")

  if !isopen(R.buffer)
    return nothing
  end

  # Error is here, why would it say EOF if the file is still being written to and open?
  # Read the length in first 4 bytes
  msglen = read(R.buffer, UInt32)

  # Then read up to that length
  bytes = read(R.buffer, msglen)
```

Note the file is still open by golang while julia is reading.

It gets traced to an error on line 399 here https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/5584620db87603fb8be313092712a9f052b8876f/base/iostream.jl#L399

I have a feeling I need to ccall some methods to get this working.

And here is the golang code

```
enc, err := os.OpenFile("data/live.bin", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE, 0660)
if err != nil {
    log.Error("Error in File Create!", err.Error())
    panic(err)
}
msgLen := make([]byte, 4)
for {
    msg := []byte("mymessage")
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(msgLen, uint32(len(msg)))
    _, err := enc.Write(msgLen)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // Write message
    _, err = enc.Write(msg)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
}
```

Comment: You are probably not seeing the writes because of buffering, so the reader never sees the changes while they are still mostly buffered.   You could try having the writer close the file and reopen for append after each write, and have the reader also reopen the file after each read.     You might also get a better response with a MWE of the reader program as well as the writer you offer above.